# How to find users in the same role

Tags: java

There is a USER entity, it has a ROLE column, it can be: ADMIN,TENANT,LANDLORD. I use Postman to make a request to output all TENANTS, how do I choose the TENANT from the USER?

Am I doing the right thing when I first want to go through all the roles and find the right one?
Then add the selected ones to the new list.
Then go through this sheet and output the one that the user requested by ID (here you need help).

I had this option:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    public User landlordGet(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        List<User> sort = userRepository.findAll();
        List<User> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User us: sort) {
            if (us.getRole().equals(Role.TENANT)){
                res.add(us);
            }
        }
        ...

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply do a "find by role" query?

Comment: @QBrute Good question, I get it like this, but what's next? `Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByRole(Role.TENANT);`

Comment: I assume there can be more than one tenant, so the return type should be `List<User>`.

Comment: There are several points to consider here: your method is called `landlordGet()` which makes me think you want to find a specific landlord. The code you posted is incomplete, but the important bit is that your method receives a parameter `Long id`. This I'm sure is the id of the user whose landlord you want to find. This, in turn, makes me think that your `User` entity should have a field of type `User` that specifies the landlord associated with that user. Hence, what you should do is find the user by id, and return its landlord field: `return userRepository.findById(id).getLandlord();`

Comment: I made a repository like this: `@Query(value = "select * from user where role = :role ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") String role);` and here is the method in the controller:`List<User> user = userRepository.findByRole("TENANT");` now how DO I FIND the right person by ID? My code: https://github.com/Blacit/TaskSpring/tree/master/src/main/java/innotechnum/task

Comment: First things first, what does the parameter your method receives represent? If it's the ID of the user whose tenant you want to find, you need one approach. If it's the ID of the tenant you want to find, you need a different approach. If it's the ID of the user whose tenant you want to find, my previous comment tells you how you should do things to achieve what you want. If it's the ID of the tenant you want to find, a mere `findById()` will work. You are needlessly complicating things.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I will definitely remember this option and will use it, thank you, friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing the right thing when I first want to go through all the roles and find the right one? Then add the selected ones to the new list. Then go through this sheet and output the one that the user requested by ID (here you need help).

Nope, not really, too much work that can be done in the SQL / database level as already mentioned in the comments.

**Note:** You should get a `List<User>` from `userRepository.findByRole(Role.TENANT);`

Since an `id` is coming from a request as a parameter, it is not clear what you want to achieve here.

If I understood correctly, then you want to go something like: 
*Get the User with the given id and check the role if it is a TENANT or not.*

**UPDATE:**

If you wanna go with roles first and then filter by id, then try:

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByRole(Role.TENANT);
Optional<User> optionalUser = users.stream().filter(user -> user.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
// Check for present or handle the missing case
```

**UPDATE 2:**

All tenants:

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByRole(Role.TENANT);
```

User with the given id and possible tenant:

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByRole(Role.TENANT);
Optional<User> optionalUser = users.stream().filter(user -> user.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
// Check for present or handle the missing case
if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
  // tenant user with given id exists - handle it
}
```

Comment: I want to make 2 controllers. 1. In one output absolutely all TENANT 2. Here output only the TENANT whose ID the user says.

Comment: Thank you, friend :)

Comment: @alexandrum What is the point of getting all tenants and then filtering that list to find the one tenant that has the provided ID, instead of directly getting that tenant by ID? It seems to me like the overhead of that could (and should) be avoided.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I agree with you, but, as I understood from OP's follow up details and comments, there can be a case that the given id is not necessarily a Tenant and has another role.

Comment: @alexandrum In that case you can still check that one user's role and only return it if it's a tenant, and return null or whatever if it isn't. No need to retrieve all of them. It's just a little nitpick on an already good and thorough answer, really, but I thought I'd point it out because little stuff like that can make OP's code better.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Indeed, fair point, and welcome perspective. I appreciate it ;)